# Selecting a whole array or converting C#

Tags: c#, arrays, syntax, charts

I have a custom data type, that is essentially stored as a long `x` and decimal `y`, and they are indexed, so I have `data.Series["example"].Values[].x` and `data.Series["example"].Values[].y` but I want to access all the elements, it keeps asking for a value expected where I have the empty square brackets, but there is like 3000+ elements, so obviously not going to enter every element manually, my end goal is I want to chart the elements, one as X and the other as Y obviously. I have it in the `DataBindXY()` method for MS charting.

Do I need to convert it to another type first(if so what type and how?), or am I just missing something simple here? But I can't figure out how to select the whole array as the data for my chart.

Thanks!

EDIT: 
I'm trying to get the maximum and minimum values now from the y array, which are of type decimal[] then set the max/min as the chart y axis range, so it displays properly, but when I try to set a "decimal yValMax = yvals.Max();" then set chart.ChartAeas[0].AxisY.Minimum = yValMin; I'm getting an ArgumentOutOfRange Exception, I have debugged it and it's getting the values correct in the yValMax and yValMin variables, but fails when it tries to set it as the Y axis boundaries? Help??

Comment: Can you share your Chart control? perhaps the Bindings that it needs?

Comment: public void DataBindXY(IEnumerable xValue, params IEnumerable[] yValues);

Comment: The charting is just from the standard .NET charting System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting. As I can't find any other charting library that is free and as good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using a `DataPointCollection`. From the docs on [`DataBindXY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455475(v=vs.110).aspx), it appears something like this should work for you.

Let `chart` below be your `DataPointCollection`:

```
chart.DataBindXY(
    data.Series["example"].Values.Select(val => val.x), 
    data.Series["example"].Values.Select(val => val.y)
);
```

This of course assuming `data.Series["example"].Values` implements `IEnumerable`. If it is a conventional `Array`, `List` or `Collection` you should be fine.

Still, if not you could make your own `List` for each (X and Y):

```
List<long> seriesX = new List<long>();
List<Decimal> seriesY = new List<Decimal>();
for (int ix = 0; ix < 3000; ix++)
{
    seriesX.Add(data.Series["example"].Values[ix].x);
    seriesY.Add(data.Series["example"].Values[ix].y);
}
chart.DataBindXY(seriesX, seriesY);
```

You said there's about 3000 records in the array of values, so I hardcoded that, but you get the picture.

Comment: Excellent thanks, making progress! Just getting a KeyNotFoundException now for some reason, when clearly it is otherwise I wouldn't be able to select it.

Comment: See edit. You can make your own `List`. What is the definition of your data series object and the value arrays?

Comment: Ok great thanks. So how do I put it if I don't know how many there will be, it will be different everytime I download the data, so the 3000 was just a ballpark figure, how would I enter it not knowing the amount, ix < ?

Comment: public struct CustomDataType with a public long x and public decimal y inside. The above List making code you suggest seems to fail on the X one, saying cannot convert from long to int and System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Add(int) has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Ah! `long`! Missed that detail. Edited to fix.

Comment: Still getting a KeyNotFoundException for the .x value, damn it! y is fine, x is having issues.

Comment: `DataBindXY()` says it will take `Series` as the inputs where `IEnumerable`s go. It appears you are indexing `Series` objects with code such as `data.Series["example"]`, have you tried passing those in? What is the structure of `data`?

Comment: Got it to work! Hooray! Just have to figure out how to chart properly now haha, Y scale is off a bit!

Comment: Thanks for the help Gutblender!!

Comment: I'm trying to get the maximum and minimum values now from the y array, which are of type decimal[] then set the max/min as the chart y axis range, so it displays properly, but when I try to set a "decimal yValMax = yvals.Max();" then set chart.ChartAeas[0].AxisY.Minimum = yValMin; I'm getting an ArgumentOutOfRange Exception, I have debugged it and it's getting the values correct in the yValMax and yValMin variables, but fails when it tries to set it as the Y axis boundaries? Help??

Comment: It's best to post that as a separate question...and if possible post more code.